# Node.js Pdf Generation with dynamic tables

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I need help to achieve multi page pdf generation in node.js . I have tried with html-pdf a freeware. I have six table's i have in my angluar(html) page. I want to hide any table during run time, if the check box is checked. i have tried with ng-show/hide. But is not working. So that, i was tried to design a html template in node.js, it works fine if i display entire page. I want to show only particular table's according to the values of an array sent from angular to node. In here myProject.html contains all my table design. I know how to hide tables in angular. That's using ng-hide/show. But i don't know how to achieve the same in node.js server side. Is there any possibility to use angularjs in this html-pdf modules. Anyone tell me.
Any help would be grateful.

My sample code snippet:

```
var html = fs.readFileSync('./public/pages/myProject.html', 'utf8');


var content1 = fs.readFileSync('./public/pages/footer.html', 'utf8');
var options = {
filename: './public/pdf/reports.pdf', format: 'Letter', "type": "pdf", 
"font-family": "Calibri",  


//    //Footer options
"footer": {
    "height": "28mm",
    "contents": content1
},
//    //Page option
"border": {
    "top": "0.2in",
    "bottom": "0.1in",
    "right": "0.5in",
    "left": "0.5in"
}
}; 

pdf.create(html, options).toFile(function (err, res) {
if (err) return console.log(err);
console.log(res); // { filename: '/tmp/html-pdf-8ymPV.pdf' }
});
```

Comment: Please elaborate what exactly you want to do. Do you have a normal webpage open with a "generate PDF" button and clicking that should get node to do that, considering the current state of the web app?

Comment: Yeah. I can able to generate a pdf with normal webpage when click a button node do that. But what i wanted to do is, i have to generate a pdf at server side node.js code. Clearly, i have multiple check boxes in html (i.e angular side). Each check box has a table with different design and data from server. if i click on two check boxes the corresponding tables only converted to pdf with data. Only risk i had seen is that i have designed all the tables in one html file. How do i hide or omit rest of tables. if i select 2 check boxes  in the front end, all tables are generated as pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Phantomjs it is. Trust me, my man. We have been using it to generate all our bills and invoices(of course dynamic data)

`EDIT` per comment request.

```
phantom.create(function(ph) {
    ph.createPage(function(page) {
        page.set('paperSize',{
            format:'Letter',
            margin: {
                'top':'0in',
                'bottom':'0in',
                'left':'0in',
                'right':'0in'
            }
        });
        page.set('content',templates.bill(data));
        page.set('settings.loadImages',true);
        page.render('/tmp/file.pdf',function() {
            ph.exit();
            callback(null,'/tmp/file.pdf');
        });
    });

});
```

where `templates.bill` is a jade compile function (returns string);

Comment: how are you handling such dynamic tables to be generated as pdf using html-pdf module. Can you place your project.

Comment: is Phantom.js free ware with MIT license

Comment: @NandhaKing, sorry was busy these two days. I'll put part of code in edits. Generally, I use jade to generate html and then use phantomjs to turn it into pdf.

Comment: is phantom.js  freeware with MIt license. Please let me know asap.

Comment: can you upload your project for my reference

Comment: sorry. But I'm supposed to use only free ware with MIT license only. So that, I'm asking you several times